# How to translate text in controller file Prestashop

Tags: php, overriding, translation, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I overrided a controller file (CartController)... and I get product condition (New) And i'll be "Nouveau" at French site. I use following code, but it wasn't work. How can i fix that?

in /override/controllers/front/CartController.php:

```
[...] 
$list_product = $cart_current->getProducts();
foreach ($list_product as $index => $product){
    $product_current = new ProductCore($product['id_product'],true);
    $result['label'] = $this->l($product_current->condition); /* Translation? */
}
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

First I'll suggest to fix your code like this:

```
[...] 
$list_product = $cart_current->getProducts();
foreach ($list_product as $index => $product){
    $product_current = new Product($product['id_product'],true); // Product not ProductCore
    $result['label'] = $product_current->condition; // Translation not here in the 'controller' but we make in the 'view'
}
[...]
```

Then in the 'view' (cart.tpl/product.tpl):

```
[...]
/*
You have to comment this translations to avoid displaying. This is a workaround used also for the months.
{l s='New'} // {l s='New' mod='mymodule'} if you are in your module tpl
{l s='Used'} // Like above
*/
{l s='%s' sprintf=[$result['label']]}
[...]
```

Comment: Is there any ways else to do that in controller file?

Comment: You have to use the `Translate` class, but I don't advise to do that way... It's more correct this, to separate 'logic' from the 'view'... Because you have a 'variable' string to translate, so you have to translate first all possible values.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It´s better practice override classes/Cart.php, function getProducts
and add in query

```
, p.`condition`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using following after adding the translated text for 'New' in any of your modules translations

Translate::getModuleTranslation()

in place of

$this->l()